# How can I store objects between bookmarklet calls?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, store

I wrote some bookmarklets to automate some tasks on a webpage. I'd like to be able to store a value somehow, so that when I run a bookmarklet the second time, it will see that it exists, and try to use it.

I'd like to be able to do that using pure javascript. Kind of like greasemonkey's storage.

Comment: On the same page, or across pages/pageloads?

Comment: On the same page. However, the page may be open in more than one tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to save the value between domains you can use JavaScript cookies, by using  `document.cookie`.
The w3 have a simple example: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp,
and here's another example from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533693%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: one more question:will the cookie be seen across all the tabs that have the page open?

Comment: From a quick test it looks like it does (on Firefox), though different browsers may behave, well, differently.

Comment: Note that cookies are sent to the server when you reopen the page (or open any other page from the same domain).